# How to subtract part of a list from itself?

Tags: python, list, subtraction

I have two lists of equal length. One, 'ids' is a list of numbers 1,2,3,5,6,8 etc. The other is a list of 0's and 1's.

For ids, I can successfully subtract 30% of the list like so.

```
trainingids = list(set(ids)-set(ids[0:int(len(ids)*0.3)]))
testingids = list(set(ids)-set(trainingids))
```

This works. However when I do the same thing for the other list, case_ids

```
trainingcase_ids = list(set(case_ids)-set(case_ids[0:int(len(case_ids)*0.3)])) 
testingcase_ids = list(set(case_ids)-set(trainingcase_ids))
```

trainingcase_ids returns an empty list. What could be causing this? Is there a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to write here?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  What do you mean by substract 30%? You want to remove some elements ?  Otherwise, looking at your problem description and your code: 
{0,1} - {0,1} = {}, hence it seems logical to get an empty list

Comment: I used the set argument because it was what worked for the previous list. I'm a very new, very poorly skilled coder. I see now why set doesnt work. 

What I'm trying to do is reduce the length of the list by removing 30% of its elements from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in other answers/comments, the `set` is converting your list of `0`s and `1`s to `{0, 1}`.

I'm not completely certain of what you are trying to do, since `set` implies you want to remove duplicates. If you don't want that, then a simple slice, slightly different than what you have should give you what you want:

```
def subtract_last_thirty_percent(list_instance):
    seventy_percent_index = round(len(list_instance) * 0.7)
    return list_instance[:seventy_percent_index]

training_case_ids = subtract_last_thirty_percent(case_ids)
```

#### UPDATE

Since you mentioned in a comment that you want to split a list into two sections, one with the first 70% and one with the last 30%, here's how you'd do that:

```
def split_at_seventy_percent(list_instance):
    i = round(len(list_instance) * 0.7)
    return list_instance[:i], list_instance[i:]

training_case_ids, testing_case_ids = split_at_seventy_percent(case_ids)
```

Comment: Just a remark. Here you assumed he wants to remove the first 30% whereas his code suggested he wanted to remove the last 30%, which is the solution I proposed.

Comment: I wasn't aware set would be removing duplicates, that is not what I want to do. I'm trying to divide ids and case_ids each into two parts. One part with 70% of its elements, and the other with the remaining elements.

Comment: Thanks @akasolace I adjusted this. Looks like there are a number of similar solutions.

Comment: @newtothis thanks for the additional info. I added a new solution to this answer to give you a 70% chunk and a 30% chunk.

Comment: Also note that the function could easily be adjusted to split at other percentages by passing in a value for the `0.7` that is hard-coded.

Comment: I think I see why that works. When I try to input ids and case_ids for list_instance, I receive 'TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method'

Comment: I think I see why, I need to add an integer output because the decimal returns a decimal portion of the list.

Comment: @gliemezis This solution works by changing the '//' to '*'. I also wanted to say thank you for your patience. I'm very new to coding and not a natural at it either. It's also not my major haha. I really appreciate your help with this problem

Comment: You're right @newtothis! Good catch there! I was a music major in college, so don't worry about it, you'll be fine :)

Comment: I also added `round()` to give you a more accurate index closer to the 70% mark. `int()` will always round down.

Answer (score 0):

```
trainingcase_ids = list(set(case_ids)-set(case_ids[0:int(len(case_ids)*0.3)]))
                 = list({0,1} - {0,1})
                 = list({})
                 = []
```

maybe, you just want this to remove the last 30% of elements from the list:

```
trainingids = ids[int(len(ids)*0.3):]  #remove the first 30%
trainingids = ids[:1-int(len(ids)*0.3)]  #remove the last 30%
```